# aspx.net Adding meta tag sifts control ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  aspx application then i added `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` to the head and after that all controlls ID where shift up by 1 ctl03_lHeading -> is now ctl04_lHeading ..

Is this common behavior?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<META> in way you specified damages xhtml organisation of document, 
Try following:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"/>;
```

(accent on closing slash).
It is also recomended to use ASP.Net @ OutputCache directive

or something like this:

```
 <%
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  %>
```